# How do I get the Content-Encoding in a POCO::Net::HTTPResponse object?

Tags: c++, httpresponse, poco

I'm fetching a server page using Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession with an appropriate Poco::Net::HTTPRequest, which works fine. Now I get a response back, and sometimes the returned page will be gzipped.

I need to find out when that is the case, so that I may deflate if necessary. The HTTP header that should indicate this, is Content-Encoding: gzip; but there's no getContentEncoding() method in Poco::Net::HTTPResponse.

Here's a non-working snippet (because there's no resp.getContentEncoding()):

```
// resp is the Poco::Net::HTTPResponse object,
// sess is the Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession
std::istream &in = sess.receiveResponse(resp);

// Get the server-returned body as a string (potentially deflate)
std::ostringstream serveroutput;
if (resp.getContentEncoding() == "gzip") { 
    Poco::InflatingInputStream
        inflater(in, Poco::InflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_GZIP);
    Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(inflater, serveroutput);
} else 
    Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(in, serveroutput);

// Now we can get at the body as a string
std::string txt = serveroutput.str();
```

Does anyone know how to get at the raw headers, so that I can inspect the header Content-Encoding myself, or of another useful method to determine whether a server response is gzipped?

Answer (score 2):

if the server set the Content-Encoding header
you could get the encoding value like the following.

> resp.get("Content-Encoding")